# Javascript: Is there an equivalent of lua's _G in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, lua, global

In lua, I can do the following:

```
_G.print("Hello world")
print("Hello world")
```

And it will both print the same string to the screen.
Is there a way to access the global object in javascript? I mean like

```
_G.console.log === console.log
true
```

It will be really helpful in my use case (I want to prevent any code injection on my website by scanning the global object for changes)

Comment: I think it's `window` you looking for...  for eg, `window.console.log`

Comment: It doesnt work in node.js (I preffer an universal solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In browsers you can use `window` or `self`. In Node you can use `global`. However this is not standardized in general, but [there is a proposal for standardizing](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-global) it. The proposal also shows an environment agnostic way to get the global object:

> ```
> var getGlobal = function () {
>     // the only reliable means to get the global object is
>     // `Function('return this')()`
>     // However, this causes CSP violations in Chrome apps.
>     if (typeof self !== 'undefined') { return self; }
>     if (typeof window !== 'undefined') { return window; }
>     if (typeof global !== 'undefined') { return global; }
>     throw new Error('unable to locate global object');
> };
> ```